# Cygwin cannot create .ssh

Tags: git, ssh, cygwin

I'm having some trouble using Git with cygwin.

> "Could not create directory '/home/Craig/.ssh'. The authenticity of
>   host 'github.com (207.97.227.239)' can't be established. RSA key
>   fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48. Are
>   you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no Host key
>   verification failed. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly"

is being displayed whilst trying to connect to github using SSH. I've also tried using https:// as the remote path but to no success.

I'm running windows 7.

Comment: This might need to be moved to superuser.

Comment: " Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no Host key verification failed" There's a surprise.

Comment: I have typed yes, the no was just to get an example error message. (hint: it's the same one.)

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me!
http://ekawas.blogspot.co.uk/2007/03/solving-pesky-ssh-issues-in-cygwin.html

> First, locate the file called `'passwd'` in your `C:\path\to\cygwin\etc` directory and open it with wordpad.
>
> Second, replace the text
> `/home/YOUR_NAME`
> with
> `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/YOUR_NAME`

Comment: Yup, this is one possible problem: if you have changed the cygwin home folder to point to the Windows home, it is not enough to just set the `HOME` env variable. The `/etc/passwd` file must also be edited, in order to point to your actual home folder. Git seems to rely on that (instead of first checking the `$HOME` var). Also remember that, starting on Windows 7, your home folder will be on `/cygdrive/c/Users/YOUR_NAME` instead of `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/YOUR_NAME`.

Comment: I changed how Cygwin mounts the C drive so it's at `/c/` instead of `/cygdrive/c/` and I got the same issue as this question and this answer fixed it (of course, I changed it to `/c/Users/YOUR_NAME` because of what I just said and I am on Windows 7 (which has `C:\Users` instead of `C:\Documents and Settings` it'd seem.))

Answer (score 1):

maybe the permissions to your home directory are interfering with `ssh`'s ability to create the `known_hosts` file?

go to your home directory and create a folder called `.ssh`, and a blank file called `known_hosts` inside of it.  then set the permissions on the file to 644.

```
cd ~
mkdir .ssh
touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

then try ssh again and see if the result is any different.  (note: you'll have to say yes when asked if you want to continue connecting the first time.  then that server will be added to the `known_hosts` list and you shouldn't be prompted anymore after that.)

Comment: .ssh already exists in my home directory, I have created and chmod'd the known_hosts file, but to no positive effect.

My home dir is currently set as /cygdrive/c/Users/Craig, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `yes` when you are asked if you want to continue

Comment: I have done so. The 'no' was to reproduce the error message to post on here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer by diannal, if you don't have a `passwd` file under `etc` folder in Cygwin root folder, then you can first create one by issuing this command:

`mkpasswd -l -p "$(cygpath -H)" > /etc/passwd`

Comment: This did indeed create a passwd file, but sadly nowhere was I referencing `home`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sysinternals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to log the file system accesses that take place when you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Documents and Settings folder of your local machine, create the folder home\. For some reason, cwRsync won't create these folders for you. I didn't change my cygpath, so I created mine in C:\Program Files\cwRsync\home\.